# Threadsafe factory pattern

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I'am coding some simple graph manager and i decied to use factory pattern to create edges for my graph. I'am just beginning to learn design-patterns and threads.

I created factory with return some objects(edges), create method, code:

```
public Edge<T> CreateEdge(Vertex<T> firstVertex, Vertex<T> secondVertex)
{
    var edge = new Edge<T>(firstVertex, secondVertex, _nextIndex);

    _nextIndex++;

    return edge;
}
```

And here is my problem. What if that factory will be shared by multiple threads is possible that the return several edges with same index.

What is the best solution of this problem? 
Should i use lock or some mutex? 
Or it is the fault of my bad design classes, use factory?

Edit #1:
Change IncreaseIndex() -> _nextIndex++; mistake when wrote it.

Comment: Is NextIndex a property? That's what I'd assume based off of the name but just want to be sure

Comment: Yes, my mistake when typing it. Corrected

Comment: You may want to take a step back and consider whether you really want multiple threads mutating the graph at the same time.  Shared mutable state with threading can get very tricky, very fast.  There may be other ways to structure your problem so that you can do work in parallel on nicely isolated chunks of data with minimal synchronization between threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
long _index;

var nextIndex = Interlocked.Increment(ref _index);
```

That will ensure your index remains unique across threads. Using a simple field makes the most sense here, since it's a property of your edge factory class.

Comment: Thank for your answer. This solves my problem. I never use/heared before of Interlocked class. I think it can be very hepful now and in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to wrap the IncreaseIndex functionality in a lock, or you could pass the management of the indexes to a singleton ([Jon Skeet's Singleton implementation](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)).

Comment: Thank for your answer. I considered using singleton but it limits me because it can happen, the situation that i have several graphs and each should has its owned edge factory.